# How to replace "strange characters

Tags: texniccenter, german

I have many symbols looking like this:

[image]

How can I replace them? Using the replace-function does not work in this case:

[image]

("Weitersuchen" does not yield any result)

**Edit:**
When I open the document it looks like

[image]

And the encoding says

[image]

Comment: Can you try and open the file with the correct encoding? You could try a different editor (Notepad++ comes to mind).

Comment: @Christoph Texniccenter is now an obsolete editor. Kurt's answer is excellent.

Comment: @Sebastiano Why is Texniccenter obsolete / no longer in use?

Comment: @Christoph TeXnicCenter is not obsolete, it is just no longer actively developed.

Comment: @samcarter where do you have that information from?

Comment: @Christoph If you look at the source code (https://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/code/ci/default/tree/) it's been a while since the last updates.

Comment: @Christoph I have always used Texniccenter. Sometimes I have detected problems with compilation due, for example, to new versions of Adobe Reader. I am currently using TeXworks.

Answer (score 3):

In TeXnicCenter you can find the actual encoding of the displayed file shown in the last line (see red circle):

[image]

Because you use an german TeXnicCenter Iyou can change the encoding with TeXnicCenter with the following commands:

Choose in the menu `Datei`, then `Speichern unter...`. In the following Windows you can change the encoding from `ansi` to `utf-8` (see red circle):

[image]

change it to `utf-8`:

[image]

and do not forget to click on `speichern`. Then click on `Ja` in window `Speichern unter bestätigen`.

Now you will see the new encoding (and changed display of umlauts) in the TeXnicCenter window:

[image]

Comment: +1 because I didn't realise that the encoding is shown. But it seems it does not work (see my edit above). No matter which encoding I choose, the file looks the same in Texniccenter. Do you have an idea? As you can see, the initial encoding guess IS UTF-8...

Comment: Either l double clicked it or l opened the file from texniccenter.